# How to make a program wait for a lock on a sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.x

I have a program that runs as part of a larger process with the sole purpose being to safely copy a sqlite database to another folder for back-up.  Only problem is that my production run just went down because the database was locked by other processes.  Is there a way I can specify for this program to wait to obtain a lock?  It is okay if it holds up the rest of the program by a few seconds.

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
import shutil
import optparse
import os
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="[%(levelname)s] - %(message)s")
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)

def sqlite3_backup(db_file, backup_dir):
    print 'DB is: ', db_file + '\n', 'Backup Dir is: ', backup_dir
    if not os.path.isdir(backup_dir):
        raise Exception("Backup directory does not exist: {0}".format(backup_dir))

    with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
        logging.info('Connected to the database.')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('begin immediate')
        shutil.copy(db_file, backup_dir)
        logging.info('Closing the database.')

usage = "%prog [options] db-file backup-dir"
description = """\
Backup sqlite3 database to a directory, appending a datestamp on the backup."""

def get_options():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=usage, description=description)
    opts, args = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) != 2:
        raise parser.error("Incorrect number of parameters")

    opts.databasefile, opts.backupdir = args
    return opts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    opts = get_options()
    sqlite3_backup(opts.databasefile, opts.backupdir)
```

Comment: Perhaps something like a Try: Except: where the Except: waits for a couple seconds and then tries again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    opts = get_options()
    for i in range(90): #give up after 90 seconds
        try:
            sqlite3_backup(opts.databasefile, opts.backupdir)
        except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
            if "locked" in str(e):
                 time.sleep(1)
            else:
                 raise
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("OK Backup sucess!")
            sys.exit(0)
   sys.stderr.write("Unable to aquire database lock...")
   sys.exit(1)
```

Is one way you might do this ...

I would also recommend using an ORM as I think most ORM's may implement this sort of thing for you behind the scenes (maybe im wrong)